# Eclipse Juno 4.2 Google Plugin not installing: Cannot complete install because one or more required items could not be found

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

This is the error message I get:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google App Engine Tools for Android 3.1.0.v201208080121-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.mobile.android.feature.feature.group 3.1.0.v201208080121-rel-r42)
```

I've tried numerous things including manually downloading the file from [here](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip) and also I snooped around StackOverflow and I tried just moving all the plugins from the manual download into the plugins folder of my Eclipse. That didn't help me though because my perspective did not update with the plugins and I couldn't find the "Create New Web Application" option. I've also read some things about the XML file being wrong but I can't find it and those were for other Eclipse versions so I don't know if it applies to me.

I also tried excluding Google App Engine Tools for Android 3.1.0 but then it just says the next one in the list can't be found.

I'll be more than happy to provide anymore information. I am running Eclipse Juno 4.2 and Java 1.7 (I also have 1.6 installed though). I am using a Windows 7 PC. Thank you guys so much! I just want to code :[

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a very old question but recently I found a solution to my problem so I am going to personally update the answer. For some reason, Eclipse Classic 4.2.2 Juno does not come with some of the required packages. After talking to some people, they recommended simply downloading [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2) which simply comes with most of the packages necessary. From there, it just worked!

My friend also mentioned you could try to manually download the packages on Eclipse Classic but that is far more of a hassle.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I did not work for me with this URL: `http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2`

It worked with this one: `http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.8`

I just changed `4.2` to `3.8`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem I was downloading with **120 kb/s** every time the download breaks down 
when I moved to another place and downloaded the plugin with highest speed **400 kb/s** It successfully downloaded and no problems found 
You might think that issue is out of logic but that what I reached so far 
Hope that Helps